# How to turn a comma seperated value TXT into a CSV for machine learning

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, python-3.6, genfromtxt

How do I turn this format of TXT file into a CSV file?

```
Date,Open,high,low,close  
1/1/2017,1,2,1,2  
1/2/2017,2,3,2,3  
1/3/2017,3,4,3,4
```

I am sure you can understand? It already has the comma -eparated values.
I tried using numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> table = np.genfromtxt("171028 A.txt", comments="%")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Smith\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1551, in genfromtxt
    fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rb'))
  File "C:\Users\Smith\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 151, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode)
  File "C:\Users\Smith\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 501, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: 171028 A.txt not found.
```

I have (S&P) 500 txt files to do this with.

Comment: I am reviewing here in the mean time. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

Comment: The error is that the file is not found, it has not got as far as looking at its format.  Check that the file `171028 A.txt` (which is a strange name) exists in the current directory.

Comment: How can python find the 171028 A.txt?

Comment: It looks in the current directory unless you give it the file's path - no different to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` module. You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

```
import csv

txt_file = 'mytext.txt'
csv_file = 'mycsv.csv'

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter=',')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w+'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @dclarke's comment, check the directory from which you run the code.  As you coded the call, the file *must* be in that directory.  When I have it there, the code runs without error (although the resulting table is a single line with four `nan` values).  When I move the file elsewhere, I reproduce your error quite nicely.

Either move the file to be local, add a local link to the file, or change the file name in your program to use the proper path to the file (either relative or absolute).